# Angular QueryList returns different types than click from event listener

Tags: angular

I have a problem comparing the content of a list of `QueryList<ElementRef>`. I like to distinguish some elements to build a closing logic for a menu.

I have some buttons in a toolbar, these buttons are Angular Material buttons of type mat-button. The buttons are assigned by #navButton to get them in the QueryList. The problem is, the type of the clicked button (nav-button) from the event listener is different then the types in the QueryList. If I use a normal button instead of Material mat-button my code runs as expected.

What is the reason to have different types in QueryList than the event listener? What can I do?

I posted my code on GitHub: https://github.com/Christoph1972/AngularMaterialHeaderTemplate

Please can you have a look into it? The important lines of code are in main-header.component.ts and main-header.component.html

Kind Regards
Christoph

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to get ElementRefs of the element provide it in `read` config field.

```
@ViewChildren('navButton', {read: ElementRef})
listOfNavButtons!: QueryList<ElementRef>;
```

in this case you will get QueryList of element refs of all the elements that match

And changing the comparison to: `if (e.target === x.nativeElement.firstChild || e.target === x.nativeElement)`

Comment: for mat-button if condition should be like this (firstChild) : e.target === x.nativeElement.firstChild

Comment: Thanks a lot for your advice! I changed the code, but the result is equal. Do I have to change more code? Sorry, I’m new in this topic.

Comment: nw. I guess you want to have mat-button directive for all buttons. So, at first  apply what Andrei said. Then, line 41 of your code should be like this :       if (e.target === x.nativeElement.firstChild) {

Comment: Yes, that’s it, the combination of both is the solution! :-)

Comment: Ok line 41 should be like this :       if (e.target === x.nativeElement.firstChild || e.target === x.nativeElement) {